# two kafka versions running on same cluster

Tags: apache-kafka

I am trying to configure two Kafka servers on a cluster of 3 nodes. while there is already one Kafka broker(0.8 version) already running with the application. and there is a dependency on that kafka version 0.8 that cannot be disturbed/upgraded .

Now for a POC, I need to configure 1.0.0 since my new code is compatible with this version and above...

**my task is to push data from oracle to HIVE tables. for this I am using jdbc connect to fetch data from oracle and hive jdbc to push data to hive tables. it should be fast and easy way...**

I need the following help

1. can I use spark-submit to run this data push to hive?
2. can I simply copy kafka_2.12-1.0.0 on my Linux server on one of the node and run my code on it. I think I need to configure my Zookeeper.properties and server.properties with ports not in use and start this new zookeeper and kafka services separately??? please note I cannot disturb existing zookeeper and kafka already running.

kindly help me achieve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i am able to achieve two kafka version 0.8 and 1.0 running on the same server with respective zookeepers.

steps followed:
1. copy the version package folder to the server at desired location
2. changes configuration setting in zookeeper.properties and server.propeties(here you need to set port which are not in used on that particular server)
3. start the services and push data to kafka topics.

Note: this requirement is only for a POC and not an ideal production environment. as answered above we must upgrade to next level rather than what is practiced above.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure running two very memory intensive applications (Kafka and/or Kafka Connect) on the same machines is considered very safe. ***Especially*** if you do not want to disturb existing applications. Realistically, a rolling restart w/ upgrade will be best for performance and feature reasons. And, no, two Kafka versions should not be part of the same cluster, unless you are in the middle of a rolling upgrade scenario.

If at all possible, please use new hardware... I assume Kafka 0.8 is even running on machines that could be old, and out of warranty? Then, there's no significant reason that I know of not to even use a newer version of Kafka, but yes, extract it on any machine you'd like, use perhaps use something like Ansible, or preferred config management tool you choose, to do it for you.

You can share the same Zookeeper cluster actually, just make sure it's not the same settings. For example,

Cluster 0.8

```
zookeeper.connect=zoo.example.com:2181/kafka08
```

Cluster 1.x

```
zookeeper.connect=zoo.example.com:2181/kafka10
```

Also, not clear where Spark fits into this architecture. Please don't use JDBC sink for Hive. Use the proper HDFS Kafka Connect sink, which has direct Hive support via the metastore. And while the JDBC source might work for Oracle, chances are, you might already be able to afford a license for GoldenGate